# XAMPP Error: Apache Attempting to start Apache service... and error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I looked through a lot of posts but I did not find the answer. So I decided to ask.

I have problem with my XAMPP.

When i am trying to launch apache nothing happens. Just Attempting to start Apache service...

When i am trying to launch MySQL i can see only this:

> 18:26:33  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 18:26:33  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing
> dependencies,
>
> 18:26:33  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by
> another method.
>
> 18:26:33  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>
> 18:26:33  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 18:26:33  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 18:26:33  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums

log here:

> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using
>
> innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be
>
> removed in future releases, together with the option
>
> innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count
>
> buffer pool pages 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB
>
> memory heap is disabled 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB:
>
> Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions 2015-11-10
>
> 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used 2015-11-10
>
> 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32
>
> instructions 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing
>
> buffer pool, size = 16.0M 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB:
>
> Completed initialization of buffer pool 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348
>
> [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda. 2015-11-10
>
> 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB
>
> (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number
>
> 1835027 2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s)
>
> not yet started 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is
>
> disabled. 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP:
>
> '::'. 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>
> 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready
>
> for connections. Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306
>
> mariadb.org binary distribution 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note]
>
> C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0
>
> events 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5732 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread
>
> exiting. 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log
>
> sequence number 1835037 2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note]
>
> C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

Comment: Maybe port 80 is blocked, for Apache (often with Skype or with IIS).

Comment: Try change ports numbers for Apache and MySQL.

Comment: Please take a look into the apache error log file. That will reveal what the actual issue is.

Comment: My skype use 29737

Comment: When i'am trying open apache error log. every i can see is file does not exist...

Comment: which port should i choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change ServerName localhost:80 to ServerName localhost:8080, save file xampp\apache\conf\htpd.conf, reset Apache in xampp\xamp-control.exe and see does Apache is working.